# Insert in to two tables

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert in to two tables at once? I need to insert some data in to a table(contactinformation) and then based on the primary key insert in to a userstable and have the primarykey set as a field (foreign key) . Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to perform the insertion operation on both of the tables in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a procedure for this.

```
DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc1` (contactinformation colums... usertable columns...)  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO contactinformation values(contactinformation colums ...);
    INSERT INTO usertable values(LAST_INSERT_ID(), contactinformation colums ...);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

`contactinformation colums...` means the column definitions of contactinformation table.
`usertable columns...` means the column definitions of usertable table.

After the first insert you can get the insert id if contactinformation table has any auto column. Then use that key in the second insert statement.

Comment: is this a stored procedure or a trigger?

Comment: Its stored procedure. See there is `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Could you give us the schema of `usertable` and `contactinformation` ? Then I'll understand better and change my procedure accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can insert into an Updatable or Insertable View that can reference two different table with a JOIN, take a look at the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html) .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on `table1` to insert the same values on `table2`.